# modal form not creating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have created forms in rails with no problems before, but this is my first time doing it in a modal and I am not sure if that effects things. I don't think it does, but you never know. The problem is that new users are not being saved, and I am getting no useful errors as to why. Here is my form, in the modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">

        <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

            <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', :required => true %><br>

            <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', :required => true %><br>

            <%= f.label :user_name %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :user_name, class: 'form-control', :required => true %><br>

            <%= f.label :password %><br>
            <%= f.password_field :password_digest, class: 'form-control', :required => true%><br>

            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', :required => true%><br>      

  </div> <!-- modal body -->

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <%= f.submit "Sign Up"%><br>
            </div>
            <% end %>
```

and here is what is in my users controller:

```
def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)

    if @user.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        redirect_to({:controller => 'application', :action => 'home'}, :notice => 'Account not created! Something is fishy.')
    end
end

def user_params
                params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :user_name, :password)
            end
```

More than likely, I am missing something. My question is two part: A)what is wrong and B)how can I stop the modal window from closing and have it display the appropriate error to the user giving them a chance to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

instead of:

```
@user = User.create(user_params)
```

Because, you are trying to `save` the user after this call.

When you use `create`, it calls `create` followed by `save`.

If you use: `User.new(user_params)`, it will just load the user object with the specified `user_params` but will not save it. In the next line, when you call: `@user.save` then the user object will be saved if valid. Otherwise, not.

Also, you can try using: `@user.save!` instead of `@user.save`. Because, when you try to save an object using `save!` method, it will raise an exception if it can't save the object properly. That way, you will know if something went wrong.

Comment: The weirdest thing is I originally had it as @user = `User.new(user_params)` for the longest time and it didn't work. I swear! So I second guessed myself and changed it to User.create to try that right (and failed) before posting here....now that I have switched it back, upon your suggestion, it works!!! grrrr! and sigh of relief. lol. thanks! will mark this as the answer in a few mins when I am allowed to

Comment: It's really weird when someone downvote an answer without any comment!
Its even more weird when the answer is actually correct and solved the problem.

Comment: I agree, I saw that and up voted it immediately to balance it out. I for one, appreciate you help ;)

Comment: BTW if you have any suggestions as to the second part of my question: how stop the modal from closing and to render any errors to the modal (instead of the page body) when needed - please do share!! Thanks!

Comment: @HolyMoly To render the errors in the modal, you could use Ajax. Here is a good tutorial which shows how to show the errors in modal using Ajax: http://ericlondon.com/2014/03/13/rails-4-submit-modal-form-via-ajax-and-render-js-response-as-table-row.html
Check it out! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the elements/tags "" should inside form_for becuase closing tag is inside of it.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <div class="modal-body">
      ......your stuff fields here
   </div> <!-- modal body -->
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit "Sign Up"%><br>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if I am correct... it looks like I may not be closing something most likely because this is not all the code from the modal, just the form body, but there are divs above and more closing tags below

Comment: I understand in above code, your div="modal body" is outside the form and the end tag of div="modal body" is inside the form. So if I am right, code will not react properly.

Comment: no it just looks that way because i did not put the entire module code up, just the part that i though mattered, the form. Everything is closed correctly, the problem was `@user = User.create` instead of `@user = User.new` - it is working now, but thanks for taking a moment to help out ;)